# initial height of autosized textarea with content form vue.js model

Tags: javascript, textarea, vue.js, autosize

I'm having a vue.js component which loads it's data inside the ready() block from an api via vue-resource:

```
this.$http.get('getData/book', (data) => {
   this.book = data;
});
```

the component template has a textarea which I want to autogrow according to its content; the value of the content is bound to the component model:

```
<textarea v-model="book.description" autocomplete="off" id="nta" class="autosize"></textarea>
```

after testing quite a lot of scripts and plugins I went with autosize.js from http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/ for the autogrowing part, which works really fine. only the initial height of the textarea, when the component is loaded, does not.

i tried updating the textarea after the data is loaded with

```
var element = document.getElementById('nta');
autosize.update(element);
```

which sadly has no effect.

and i tried

```
var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
evt.initEvent('autosize:update', true, false);
element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

which to my surprise empties the value of the bound data and the textarea.

a content_editable element is no alternative for me, it has to be a texarea.

can anybody help me out here?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-autosize

Comment: great, that works! only had to modify the template to `<textarea v-autosize="someData" v-model="someData">{{someData}}</textarea>` for the binding of the value to the model.
I'm afraid to say that although it works, I don't quite understand why - could you add a little explaination?

Comment: I haven't looked into the package and how it works.

Comment: i guess i have to work it out on myself then, thanks anyway. came across a problem though: it doesn't seem to work in a v-for list rendering